# Kummer Theory Proof

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, kummer-theory

I have a question about a step in proof of Kummer theorem in Kedlaya's notes (see page 8)
www.math.mcgill.ca/darmon/courses/cft/refs/kedlaya.pdf

We start with a $\alpha \in K* = K \backslash \{0\}$ with the property that $\alpha^{1/d} \not \in K$ for every proper divisor $d$ of $n$. Then he concludes that $x^n- \alpha$ is irreducible over $K$.

Why? The fact that $\alpha^{1/d} \not \in K$ states just that  $x^n- \alpha$ doesn't splits in ***linear factors*** in $K$ but naively it could be split in non linear factors, right? Or where is the error in my reasonings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed not. For instance take $K=\Bbb Q$, $n=4$ and $\alpha=-4$. Then $\alpha
$ is not a square in $K$, but
$$x^n-\alpha=x^4+4=(x^2+2x+2)(x^2-2x+2)$$
is reducible over $K$.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for this answer which obviosly solves the 
problem for given conditions as above. But I think that I
forgot to mention a substantial assumption: In the script
he assumes that $K$ contains a primitive n-th root $\zeta_n$.
Here I started a new thread since in this case the problem has
fundamentally another color: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3032382/kummer-theory-square-extension. Do you see how to cope with this one? Here your example obviously doesn't work.