# Kummer Theory Square Extension

Tags: field-theory, kummer-theory

I have a question about an argument used in the proof of Kummer theorem in Kedlaya's notes (see page 8)
www.math.mcgill.ca/darmon/courses/cft/refs/kedlaya.pdf

Let $K$ be a field which contains a n-th root $\zeta_n$. 
We consider $\alpha \in K* = K \backslash \{0\}$ with the property that $\alpha^{1/d} \not \in K$ for every proper divisor $d$ of $n$. The autor deduces that $x^n- \alpha$ is irreducible over $K$.

Why? The fact that $\alpha^{1/d} \not \in K$ states just that  $x^n- \alpha$ doesn't splits in ***linear factors*** in $K$ but naively it could be split in non linear factors, right? Or where is the error in my reasonings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\zeta$ be a primitive $n$-th root of unity. Over the Kummer extension
we have a factorisation
$$X^n-\alpha=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(X-\zeta^k\beta).$$
If $f(X)$ is a non-trivial monic factor over $K$,
then $f(X)=X^r+\cdots\pm\xi\beta^r$
where $\xi$ is some $n$-the root of unity. Therefore $\beta^r\in K$.
As $\beta^n=\alpha\in K$, then $\beta^m\in K$ where $m=\gcd(n,r)$
and $\beta^m=\alpha^{1/d}$ for $d=n/m$.

Comment: ...and $\beta^m \in K$ in a consequence of Bezout?

Comment: @KarlPeter Indeed